# Assembly pass pointer to function

Tags: assembly, x86, libc, calling-convention, fasm

I'm trying to sent DWORD variable into function as pointer paramater

```
variable1 dd 1
...
push [variable1]  ; push variable adress
call _InitPoiner
...
_InitPoiner:
    ;
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    ;
    lea eax, [ebp+8]       ; load address
    mov dword [eax], 10    ; move value 10 into that address

    pop ebp
    ret
...
push [variable1]
push sdigit ; where sdigit db '%d', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
call [printf]
```

but variable1 is 1, not 11 , why?

Comment: Making sure that you pop your vars when done yes?  Looking at your example, I see no way that the variable could ever be 11.  It starts as 1 at the `dd` assignment, then if your math in the `lea` is correct, it would then be 10.  If you were to step this through a debugger, you could check if your `lea / mov` combo is working right.  Either way, I would expect 1 or 10, not 11.  Maybe you meant to `add` instead of` `mov`?

Comment: after call _InitPoiner I added pop [variable1] and it's works.

Comment: sorry I meant to add instead of mov.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: You were assuming a _callee stack-cleanup convention_, but implemented a _caller stack-cleanup convention_. By cleaning up the stack you have efficiently fixed this problem by yourself. See [WikiPedia on calling-conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) to understand why you have fixed your problem on your own.

Comment: why I can "do not POP array after PUSH_ing him" ?

push my_array
call my_func;



push my_array 
call  my_func

Comment: Ok, moving my comment to an answer then since it seems to have got you on the right track :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making sure that you pop your vars when done?

Looking at your example, I see no way that the variable could ever be 11. It starts as 1 at the `dd` assignment, then if your math in the lea is correct, it would then be 10. If you were to step this through a debugger, you could check if your `lea / mov` combo is working right. Either way, I would expect 1 or 10, not 11.

Maybe you meant to `add` instead of `mov`?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you are not pushing the **address** of `variable1` onto the stack when you do `push [variable1]`. That pushes the 32-bit value stored at variable1 which happens to be the value of 1. To push the address you would use `push variable1` without the brackets.

When pushing values onto the stack before a call you need to restore the stack after the call.

*LEA* wasn't getting the address stored on the stack but getting the address of the stack location where the address should have been stored. I think you were looking for something like:

```
format ELF

extrn printf
public main

section '.text' executable
main:
    push variable1         ; push address of variable
    call _InitPointer
    add esp, 4             ; We pushed 4 bytes before calling function
                           ; restore the stack by adding 4

    push [variable1]       ; Push the value at address variable1
    push sdigit            ; Format specifier for printf
    call printf
    add esp, 8             ; We pushed 8 bytes of data for call
                           ; restore the stack by adding 8
    ret

_InitPointer:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]       ; There is an address at [ebp+8] that
                           ; was pushed as the 1st parameter. Put the
                           ; address in EAX

    add dword [eax], 10    ; Add the value 10 to the DWORD value that is at
                           ; address in EAX

    pop ebp
    ret

section '.data' writeable
variable1 dd 1
sdigit db '%d', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0
```

You didn't mention the platform you are on as you didn't supply a minimal complete verifiable example. The code above could be tested on Linux with:

```
fasm test.asm
gcc -o test -m32 test.o
```

When run you should get:

> 11

The equivalent *C* code would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _InitPointer (int *ptr)
{
    *ptr += 10;
    return;
}

int variable1 = 1;

int main()
{
    _InitPointer (&variable1);
    printf ("%d\n", variable1);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: If on modern versions of Linux, 32-bit programs follow [System V i386 ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf) that requires the stack be 16-byte (or 32-byte) aligned at the point of a function call. I didn't do that in the code above to keep it simplified but it should be taken into account. I'm unsure if you are on Linux or Windows. Your question doesn't say.

---

### 32-bit Windows Version

```
format PE console 4.0
include 'win32a.inc'

main:
    push variable1         ; push address of variable
    call _InitPointer
    add esp, 4             ; We pushed 4 bytes before calling function
                           ; restore the stack by adding 4

    push [variable1]       ; Push the value at address variable1
    push sdigit            ; Format specifier for printf
    call [printf]
    add esp, 8             ; We pushed 8 bytes of data for call
                           ; restore the stack by adding 8
    push 0                 ; Exit with return value 0
    call [ExitProcess]

_InitPointer:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]       ; There is an address at [ebp+8] that
                           ; was pushed as the 1st parameter. Put the
                           ; address in EAX

    add dword [eax], 10    ; Add the value 10 to the DWORD value that is at
                           ; address in EAX

    pop ebp
    ret

variable1 dd 1
sdigit db '%d', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0

data import
 library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
         msvcrt,'MSVCRT.DLL'
 import msvcrt,\
        printf ,'printf'
 import kernel32,\
        ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'
end data
```

Comment: I'm on Windows.

Comment: You said "LEA wasn't getting the address stored on the stack but getting the address of the stack location where the address should have been stored."

so if `push [variable]` is not sending address of variable, then how it was working properly? I guess `lea eax, dword[ebp+8]` was loading stack's address where was VALUE of `variable`, then `mov dword [eax], 10' was loading 10 into stack address where is that value, but how original `variable' changed? Because when we are sending parameter by value, compilator making copy (from C)

Comment: @Alatriste `push [variable1]` was pushing `variable1` by value. That placed the value 1 on the top of the stack (not the address of variable1). `lea eax, dword[ebp+8]` moved the address where the value 1 was stored on the stack (not the actual location of `variable1`) into _EAX_. You then modified the value on the stack with the `add`. Upon returning `pop [variable1]` then takes the modified value off the top of the stack and stores (copies) it to the memory address of `variable1`. Although this works, this is not how you usually pass a pointer to a function.

Comment: @Alatriste This is the reason your code didn't work until you did `pop [variable1]` because your function never actually modified the value at the memory address containing `variable1`

Comment: Now I understand, so: `lea eax, dword [ebp+8]` was loading address of the stack where was value 1. Then `add` was adding value 10 into that address (stack adress), then `pop [variable1]` was loading top of the stack  (i.e value 11) into `variable1` and then incrementing `esp` register. So that `pop` was doing copying BUT NOT function.

Comment: @Alatriste : yes